# Shopping cart for CCBill in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

We need to develop an eCommerce solution for an MP3 file seller. The files are all MP3 format and we have CCBill payment gateway.

Is there anyway to integrate CCBill with Drupal's shopping carts like Zencart smoothly (preferably without having to touch PHP code much)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll struggle to integrate Zencart with Drupal. Some have tried ([Drupal Zencart module](http://drupal.org/project/zencart)) but nothing's ever come out of it.

The preferred e-commerce solution for Drupal is [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) ([Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) is well on it's way but still a bit immature in my opinion), but there is no integration with CCBill for either module anyway.

There is a [CCBill integration module](http://drupal.org/project/ccbill) which provides rudimentary connection to CCBill's services (integrated heavily with the rules module), but even that's in beta (at best, the D7 version is still alpha).

If you need to use CCBill then Drupal probably isn't the right solution for you, unless of course you're prepared to write the payment gateway module to hook into one of Ubercart or Commerce.